# NetLogon and RPC Errors

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, group-policy, netlogon

Situation:

Co-located DCs connected by T1 to client working location. The T1 is averaging at about 2/3 usage. All 1 Active Directory.

I am trying to deploy a start-up script to clients at the working location though GPO. It seems to work on some computers and not on others, but consistently. For example, it will always work on PC1, and always NOT work on PC2. Even though at the same location . I turned on netlogon logging and below is what one of the "not working" PCs are reporting...

Once they login the other GPOs work. I know the tendency would be to say that's its a DNS issue, but the records are good and other PCs are working fine. I also re-added the computer to the domain...

Also, at the DC/server location, there are other server reporting "RPC server not responding" in relation to Netlogon start up, and the secondary DC everyone once in awhile throws a DFS error about "no endpoint from the end point mapper" about the other server...

Perhaps the DCs are over worked? Any way guys think to confirm that? Only about 90 workstations/servers for 2 DCs. 2 working locations and 1 colo facility.  I did some netstat -an to see whats going on and they are averaging 15-20 "TIME_WAIT"s

Thoughts?

```
15:27:28 [INIT] Group Policy is not defined for Netlogon
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT] Following are the effective values after parsing
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    Sysvol = C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\SYSVOL
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    Scripts = (null)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    SiteName (0) = Default-First-Site-Name
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    RpcDacl = (null)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    Pulse = 300 (0x12c)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    Randomize = 1 (0x1)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    PulseMaximum = 7200 (0x1c20)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    PulseConcurrency = 10 (0xa)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    PulseTimeout1 = 10 (0xa)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    PulseTimeout2 = 300 (0x12c)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MaximumMailslotMessages = 500 (0x1f4)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MailslotMessageTimeout = 10 (0xa)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MailslotDuplicateTimeout = 2 (0x2)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    ExpectedDialupDelay = 0 (0x0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    ScavengeInterval = 900 (0x384)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MaximumPasswordAge = 30 (0x1e)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    LdapSrvPriority = 0 (0x0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    LdapSrvWeight = 100 (0x64)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    LdapSrvPort = 389 (0x185)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    LdapGcSrvPort = 3268 (0xcc4)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    KdcSrvPort = 88 (0x58)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    KerbIsDoneWithJoinDomainEntry = 0 (0x0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DnsTtl = 600 (0x258)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DnsRefreshInterval = 86400 (0x15180)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    CloseSiteTimeout = 900 (0x384)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    SiteNameTimeout = 300 (0x12c)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DuplicateEventlogTimeout = 14400 (0x3840)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MaxConcurrentApi = 0 (0x0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    NegativeCachePeriod = 45 (0x2d)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    BackgroundRetryInitialPeriod = 600 (0x258)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    BackgroundRetryMaximumPeriod = 3600 (0xe10)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    BackgroundRetryQuitTime = 0 (0x0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    BackgroundSuccessfulRefreshPeriod = 4294967295 (0xffffffff)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    NonBackgroundSuccessfulRefreshPeriod = 1800 (0x708)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DnsFailedDeregisterTimeout = 172800 (0x2a300)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MaxLdapServersPinged = 55 (0x37)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DBFlag = 545325055 (0x2080ffff)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    MaximumLogFileSize = 20000000 (0x1312d00)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    ForceRediscoveryInterval = 43200 (0xa8c0)
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    RefusePasswordChange = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AllowReplInNonMixed = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AvoidSamRepl = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AvoidLsaRepl = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    SignSecureChannel = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    SealSecureChannel = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    RequireSignOrSeal = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    RequireStrongKey = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    SysVolReady = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    UseDynamicDns = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    RegisterDnsARecords = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AvoidPdcOnWan = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AutoSiteCoverage = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AvoidDnsDeregOnShutdown = TRUE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DnsUpdateOnAllAdapters = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    Nt4Emulator = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    DisablePasswordChange = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    NeutralizeNt4Emulator = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT]    AllowSingleLabelDnsDomain = FALSE
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT] Command line parsed successfully ...
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT] Netlogon.dll has been unloaded (recover from it).
09/16 15:27:28 [SITE] Setting site name to 'Default-First-Site-Name'
09/16 15:27:28 [SESSION] \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{1A232E93-DFF8-4177-A408-866CD52B9F83}: Transport Added (192.168.100.18)
09/16 15:27:28 [SESSION] Winsock Addrs: 192.168.100.18 (1) 
09/16 15:27:28 [DNS] Set DnsForestName to: test.local
09/16 15:27:28 [DOMAIN] test: Adding new domain
09/16 15:27:28 [DOMAIN] Setting our computer name to FRTEST037 frtest037.test.local
09/16 15:27:28 [DOMAIN] Setting Netbios domain name to test
09/16 15:27:28 [DOMAIN] Setting DNS domain name to test.local.
09/16 15:27:28 [DOMAIN] Setting Domain GUID to db465d51-0612-406f-bd7f-c2649bc8008f
09/16 15:27:28 [CRITICAL] C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\netlogon.ftj: Unable to open. 2
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT] Getting cached trusted domain list from binary file.
09/16 15:27:28 [MISC] NlpInitializeTrace succeeded 0
09/16 15:27:28 [LOGON] NlSetForestTrustList: New trusted domain list:
09/16 15:27:28 [LOGON]     0: test test.local (NT 5) (Forest Tree Root) (Primary Domain) (Native)
09/16 15:27:28 [LOGON]        Dom Guid: db465d51-0612-406f-bd7f-c2649bc8008f
09/16 15:27:28 [LOGON]        Dom Sid: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204
09/16 15:27:28 [INIT] Starting RPC server.
09/16 15:27:28 [SESSION] test: NlSessionSetup: Try Session setup
09/16 15:27:28 [SESSION] test: NlDiscoverDc: Start Synchronous Discovery
09/16 15:27:28 [MISC] DsGetDcName function called: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: DS 
09/16 15:27:32 [MISC] DsrEnumerateDomainTrusts: Called, Flags = 0x9
**09/16 15:27:44 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetDcNext: _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.test.local.: Cannot Query DNS. 1460 0x5b4
09/16 15:27:44 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetDcNext: _ldap._tcp.Default-First-Site-Name._sites.dc._msdcs.test.local.: Cannot Query DNS. 1460 0x5b4
09/16 15:27:44 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetNameIp: test.local.: No data returned from DnsQuery.
09/16 15:27:44 [MAILSLOT] Sent 'Sam Logon' message to test[1C] on all transports.
09/16 15:27:44 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetNameIp: test.local.: No data returned from DnsQuery.**
09/16 15:27:44 [MAILSLOT] Sent 'Sam Logon' message to test[1C] on all transports.
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetNameNetbios: test.local.: Cannot NlBrowserSendDatagram. (1C) 53
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetName: test.local.: IP and Netbios are both done.
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetNameNetbios: test.local.: Cannot NlBrowserSendDatagram. (1C) 53
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] DsGetDcName function returns 1355: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: DS 
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] NetpDcGetName: test.local.: IP and Netbios are both done.
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] test: NlDiscoverDc: Cannot find DC.
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] test: NlSessionSetup: Session setup: cannot pick trusted DC
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] Eventlog: 5719 (1) "test" 0xc000005e c000005e   ^...
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] DsGetDcName function called: Dom:test Acct:(null) Flags: DS NETBIOS RET_DNS 
09/16 15:27:46 [SESSION] test: NlSetStatusClientSession: Set connection status to c000005e
09/16 15:27:46 [SESSION] test: NlSessionSetup: Session setup Failed
09/16 15:27:46 [INIT] Started successfully
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] DsrEnumerateDomainTrusts: returns: 0
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] NetpDcGetName: test.local. similar query failed recently 0
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] DsGetDcName function returns 1355: Dom:test Acct:(null) Flags: DS NETBIOS RET_DNS 
09/16 15:27:46 [INIT] Group Policy is not defined for Netlogon
09/16 15:27:46 [INIT] Following are the effective values after parsing
09/16 15:27:46 [MISC] NlWksScavenger: Can be called again in 26 days (0x86e6c342)
09/16 15:27:46 [SESSION] I_NetLogonGetAuthData: (null) test
09/16 15:27:46 [CRITICAL] I_NetLogonGetAuthData: test: failed C000005E
09/16 15:27:48 [SESSION] NetrLogonGetTimeServiceParentDomain: test.local. is the parent domain. (PdcSameSite: 1)
09/16 15:27:49 [SITE] DsrGetSiteName: Returning site name 'Default-First-Site-Name' from local cache.
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] DsGetDcName function called: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: IP TIMESERV AVOIDSELF BACKGROUND 
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] NetpDcGetName: test.local. similar query failed recently 3204
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] DsGetDcName function returns 1355: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: IP TIMESERV AVOIDSELF BACKGROUND 
09/16 15:27:49 [SITE] DsrGetSiteName: Returning site name 'Default-First-Site-Name' from local cache.
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] DsGetDcName function called: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: IP TIMESERV AVOIDSELF BACKGROUND 
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] NetpDcGetName: test.local. similar query failed recently 3250
09/16 15:27:49 [MISC] DsGetDcName function returns 1355: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: IP TIMESERV AVOIDSELF BACKGROUND 
09/16 15:28:46 [MISC] DsGetDcName function called: Dom:(null) Acct:(null) Flags: DS
```

Userenv log (as requested)

```
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:859 UnloadUserProfile: Entering, hProfile = <0x730>
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:859 UnloadUserProfile: In console winlogon process
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Entering, hProfile = <0x730>
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 GetExclusionListFromRegistry: Policy list is empty, returning user list = <Local Settings;Temporary Internet Files;History;Temp;Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook>
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500>
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500 added in bucket 16
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnloadUserProfileP: Wait succeeded.  In critical section.
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 MyRegUnLoadKey: Returning 1.
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnloadUserProfileP:  Succesfully unloaded profile
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 MyRegUnLoadKey: Returning 1.
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnLoadClassHive: Successfully unmounted S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500_Classes
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnloadUserProfileP:  Successfully unloaded user classes
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnloadUserProfileP: Impersonated user
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:875 UnloadUserProfileP: Writing local ini file
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfileP: Reverting to Self
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfileP: exitting and cleaning up
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500>
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500 deleted
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfileP: Leave critical section.
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfileP: Leaving with a return value of 1
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfile: UnloadUserProfileP succeeded
USERENV(220.224) 11:38:29:890 UnloadUserProfile: returning 1
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:843 UnloadUserProfile: Entering, hProfile = <0x398>
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:843 GetInterface: Returning rpc binding handle
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:843 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:843 DropClientContext: Got client token 000007B8, sid = S-1-5-18
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:843 MIDL_user_allocate enter
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:843 DropClientContext: load profile object successfully made
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:843 DropClientContext: Returning 0
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:843 UnLoadUserProfile: Calling DropClientToken (as self) succeeded
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Entering, hProfile = <0x600>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: ImpersonateUser <000007b8>, old token is <00000000>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 GetExclusionListFromRegistry: Policy list is empty, returning user list = <Local Settings;Temporary Internet Files;History;Temp>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-19>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-19 added in bucket 12
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Wait succeeded.  In critical section.
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP:  Didn't unload user profile, Ref Count is 2
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Reverted back to user <00000000>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-19>
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-19 deleted
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Leave critical section.
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileP: Leaving with a return value of 1
USERENV(220.9d8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfileI: returning 0
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfile: Calling UnloadUserProfileI succeeded
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:859 IProfileSecurityCallBack: client authenticated.
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:859 ReleaseClientContext: Releasing context
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:859 ReleaseClientContext_s: Releasing context
USERENV(220.8c0) 11:38:32:859 MIDL_user_free enter
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:859 ReleaseInterface: Releasing rpc binding handle
USERENV(24c.ad8) 11:38:32:859 UnloadUserProfile: returning 1
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:078 InitializePolicyProcessing: Initialised Machine Mutex/Events
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:093 InitializePolicyProcessing: Initialised User Mutex/Events
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:093 LibMain: Process Name:  \??\C:\WINDOWS\system32\winlogon.exe
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:218 Entering CUserProfile::Initialize ...
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize called by winlogon
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: critical section initialized
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::Initialize: critical section initialized
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: registry key Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList opened
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-500
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-500>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-500 added in bucket 17
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000100
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-500>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-500 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1007
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1007>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1007 added in bucket 22
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 1, state is 00000000
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Ref Count is not 0
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1007>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1007 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1006
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1006>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1006 added in bucket 21
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000000
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1006>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1006 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1003
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1003>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1003 added in bucket 18
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000104
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1003>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-527237240-813497703-725345543-1003 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500 added in bucket 16
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000100
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-500 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1686
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1686>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1686 added in bucket 11
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000204
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1686>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1686 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1189
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1189>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1189 added in bucket 9
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000100
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1189>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1189 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1141
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1141>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1141 added in bucket 20
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000000
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1141>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1141 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:234 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1137
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1137>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1137 added in bucket 2
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000100
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1137>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1137 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1122
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1122>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1122 added in bucket 19
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000100
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1122>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1122 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1106
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1106>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1106 added in bucket 21
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000000
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1106>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-3926823378-3145110219-1190181204-1106 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7164
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7164>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7164 added in bucket 12
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Enter critical section.
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::GetRefCountAndFlags: Ref count is 0, state is 00000000
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock <S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7164>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock released
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashDelete: S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7164 deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::LeaveLock: Lock deleted
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::CleanupUserProfile: Leave critical section
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CUserProfile::Initialize: Proccessing S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7141
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock <S-1-5-21-2000478354-1580818891-1606980848-7141>
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: No existing entry found
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CSyncManager::EnterLock: New entry created
USERENV(218.21c) 11:39:05:250 CHashTable::HashAdd: S-1-5-21-2000478354
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever find the root cause for this?  If so, how did you fix?  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have multiple simultaneous issues.

I'd turn on USERENV debugging on a client where the script isn't running and see what comes up there. Create a registry key "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Diagnostics" and under that key, add a REG_DWORD value "RunDiagnosticLoggingGlobal" set to 1. That'll throw massive USERENV logging information into the event log. Set that, then bounce the machine with a "gpupdate /sync /boot" and have a look. (My psychic powers say DHCP media sense issues... we'll see. I'm assuming you've set "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" to "Enabled" already.)

From the DC where you took this netlogon log can you run and post the output from:

```
dcdiag /test:DNS /v
```

Let us know. This sounds like fun.

Comment: DcDiag:
The A host record(s) for this DC was found
Warning: The AAAA record for this DC was not found
[Error details: 9501 (Type: Win32 - Description: No records found for given DNS query.) - ihire.local]
The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found

Also, not sure what i am looking for in userenv, i still see the failed DNS queries in there. 

"wait for network" is enabled... 

Thoughts?